# Risc-V: What is the timing of a conditional branch to the next instruction?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, riscv

For example, take the following code, (assume branch is taken/not taken after MEM stage in a standard 5 stage pipeline).

```
    beq x1, x2, there
    no op
there: 
    addi x1, x2, 4
    lw x1, 0(x1)
```

So the branch would be taken/not taken at clock cycle 4.

The no op would be in the pipeline at cycle 2, would the `addi` instruction be loaded at cycle 3?

Or would the pipeline stall until the outcome of the branch is determined?

(meaning the `addi` instruction is loaded at cycle 5)

Comment: You mean RISC-V specifically, right?  I retagged this from [risc] to [riscv].  Also, labels themselves don't execute, just instructions.  Your title sounds like you're asking if execution falls through labels. (Which some beginners get confused about, if they're used to languages with functions that end and return implicitly.)  Your question body sounds like you're actually asking about branch prediction / speculation.

Comment: I guess that might be my question, I am extremely confused so unsure if I am even asking the right question. But yes I mean RISC-V. So I would assume in this case that the `addi` instruction would begin executing right after the no-op regardless of the fact that the branch result is unknown at cycle 3?

Comment: If it helps, "there" is just an alias for "the address of the `addi`".  It's not really present at runtime.

Comment: I modified the headline of your question; please check if my edit is correct.

Comment: RISC V is an instruction set architecture specification not a processor.  In fact, it is a family of specifications.  There are many varied implementations with different timings, ranging from simple for embedded to out-of-order for performance.  Timings are not part of the specification, for that to be relevant you have to specify a processor, whether real or hypothetical.

Comment: @ErikEidt Would you write this as "answer"? Maybe beginning with something like: "This depends on the exact CPU model..."?